# How can I change Javascript Value into percentage instead of pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I want to change my scrolltop value from 50px to something like lets say 1% of the user's screen. How could I possibly go about doing this. I was reading that a JS value can be a percentage, however it is not working for me. Here is a codepen I made to demonstrate the effect:

[link] (http://codepen.io/ericshio/pen/zBRbAY)

HTML:

```
<div class="filler"></div>
<a href="#introjump"><img class="down-arrow" src="http://www.themainconcept.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/down-arrow-wht.png" alt="down arrow wht"/></a>
```

CSS:

```
.down-arrow {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 1%;
    left: 50%;
    max-width: 3.5%;
    min-width: 3.5%;
    width: 3.5%;
    box-shadow: none;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.down-arrow:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}


.filler {
    height: 10000px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $(".down-arrow").css("opacity", 1 -
    $(window).scrollTop() / 50);
});
```

Comment: "_1% of the user's screen_" == `1vh` ; no math needed

Comment: How is this
("opacity", 1 -
not throwing an error?o0

Comment: @dandavis this throws the error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: I don't know lol @damianocelent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $(".down-arrow").css("opacity", 1 -
    $(window).scrollTop() / $(document).height()*0.5);
});
```

Comment: Hmm, that does not achieve the look I am going for. I need the opacity to hit zero when a user scrolls maybe 50-250 px. Or maybe 1-5% of their screen.

Comment: you can change the value according to that. e.g $(document).height()*0.05 for 5%

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're trying to fade out the arrow on scroll

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $(".down-arrow").css("opacity", 1 - ($(window).scrollTop() / document.body.scrollHeight));
});
```

```css
.down-arrow {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1%;
  left: 50%;
  max-width: 3.5%;
  min-width: 3.5%;
  width: 3.5%;
  box-shadow: none;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.down-arrow:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.filler {
  height: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filler"></div>
<a href="#introjump">
  <img class="down-arrow" src="http://www.themainconcept.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/down-arrow-wht.png" alt="down arrow wht" />
</a>
```

Comment: Yes, but I want it to fade out completely very close to the top. Like 50px down.

Comment: Is'nt that what you're already doing, fading it out at 50 pixels?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
.down-arrow {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 1%;
    left: 50%;
    max-width: 3.5%;
    min-width: 3.5%;
    width: 3.5%;
    box-shadow: none;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.down-arrow:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}


.filler {
    height: 50%;
}
```